# ImageMagick installation on linux - cannot be called from script

Tags: linux, php, imagemagick

I have installed ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) on a linux server (following the installation steps) - i which to migrate a php application on this new server.

```
$which mogrify
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin/mogrify
```

Although mogrify CAN be called from the shell **it cannot** be found from a server side script (php).

The script contains a system([args]) function which executes the programm [args].

So system('mogrify --someoptions') does nothing at all.

Any ideas on what is wrong? Setup of imagemagick or problem from the php script?

NOTE: The same script executes succesfully on an existing server. On the new server the call to mogrify does nothing at all (permissions and settings are the same).

Comment: What platforms?

Comment: centos 5.x distro

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path instead of just the binary name. I would imagine that /usr/local is not in the $PATH of the user running PHP.

`/usr/local/bin/mogrify`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

by settings you mean php settings? PHP Safe mode is off?
What if you use the full path to mogrify? (system('/usr/local/bin/mogrify --someoptions')
Anything in the php/apache error logs?

Comment: can't make changes easily...hundred of files and many places where the call is issued. I'll try this if everything else fails.